# How to create dynamically entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, asp.net-mvc, silverlight

How to create dynamically entities? (with its own table in SQL Server)
same or similar to Microsoft Dynamics CRM ...

and which are usable by a service oData(for example)

Comment: what are u trying to do? can u elaborate more?

Comment: I want to build an application in which users can add new fields to forms and / or entities, without changing the source code. In Microsoft CRM 4.0 and 2011 can do this.

What I know is that way you can do this in C # and NHibernate or EF or another.

(Excuse my English, I speak Spanish)

Comment: Not really. both NHibernate and EF are encouraged for strong typed objects. What you can have is VO objects which are basically key value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider reviewing this [article about Entity Framework Code First approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh126815.aspx), which should have you get going. I am not advocating you to use the Entity Framework, but it will give you an idea how things roll.

Comment: I want to build an application in which users can add new fields to forms and / or entities, without changing the source code. In Microsoft CRM 4.0 and 2011 can do this.

What I know is that way you can do this in C # and NHibernate or EF or another.

(Excuse my English, I speak Spanish)

Answer (score 0):

MS CRM (or similar large applications, like Sharepoint) do not use "plain" data layer - actual SQL tables with fields corresponding 1:1 to class and properties. They always use some kind of "data abstraction layer" which support this kind of things (like new user-created entities) by heavy usage of metadata - they actually use tables more like to "describe" virtual entities, which are decomposed and denormalised etc.

Good tip: dont try to write data layer like this by your own, try to look for one. For example, open source CMS Orchard has one, give it a look.